# More than one DN specified for the same profile in Profile DB - User profile synchronization.

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, user

I am facing a similar error as the [Link](https://wespoint.wordpress.com/2018/03/09/sharepoint-and-user-profiles-not-updated/) provides. Is there a relevant SQL query for PS Query provided in the link to delete those entries? I did find an other technet article but the [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sajiths/2014/12/03/sp2013-adimport-more-than-one-dn-specified-for-the-same-profile/) seems to be broken

When i ran the below query

```
 `SELECT UPF.[NTName], Count(UPF.NTName)    FROM [UPA-Profile-DB].[dbo].[UserProfile_Full] as UPF with (nolock)  INNER JOIN [UPA-Profile-DB].[dbo].DNLookup as DN with (nolock)  ON UPF.RecordID = DN.RecordId Group BY UPF.NTName Having Count(UPF.NTName) > 1 Order by UPF.NTName `
```

I did get the result of usernames with 2 entries. Which user has to be deleted?

Comment: What are you using? UPSS or MIM?

Comment: I am using UPSS